# creating release branch build in team city

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I am working with Team City for .net and use it for continuous integration - works well. I have it running off my main branch.

I now have a release branch - how I can I configure to set up a release branch in team city. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What I've done before is to copy the build configuration of my trunk build and then just create a new VCS root pointing at the other branch and use that in the new configuration.

Comment: So separate configuration for every branch? Any way to combine?

Comment: I guess you could have a single build configuration that builds both branches. You'd need to have separate build steps for building, unit testing, etc, of each branch. I've always liked having a separate configuration though.

Comment: @amateur you can use templates to parameterise your build, and share VCS roots among multiple projects or builds, again using parameters for the unique parts.

Answer (score 0):

Your can track several branches using Branch Specification field of VCS root. Specify wildcard for you branches like

```
+:refs/heads/release_*   (for release branches) or
+:refs/heads/*   (for all branches)
```

More details [in docs](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Working+with+Feature+Branches).

Some notes:

1. Run build button runs it for default branch. Click ellipsis -> Changes tab to select specific branch.
2. Now you cannot use artifact dependencies for specific branch. Such dependencies will always use the default branch.

Regarding issues with artifact dependencies, it's not easy to create deployment configurations from branch specific artifacts. In this case I'd go using separate configurations for each branch. Otherwise you should rely on API and/or some artifact path name parsing logic.

If you don't need per branch deployments, it's completely ok to just use branch specs approach.